# Cannot inheritance correct parent class, init takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, selenium, class, init, base-class

I have a base class

```
class Environment(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        options_for_console_log = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
        options_for_console_log['loggingPrefs'] = {'browser': 'ALL'}
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=options_for_console_log)
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        print('1', self.driver)

    def tearDown(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.close()
```

and a class what inherit base one

```
class StatusesCheckManual(Environment):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Environment).__init__()

    def test_1_add_materials(self):

        self.create_order = CreateOrder(self.driver)
        self.order_statuses = Order_manual_statuses(self.driver)
        self.order = Order(self.driver)


        self.order_id = self.create_order.create_fake_order()

        LoginAsAdmin(self.driver).login()

        self.order.go_to_order(self.order_id)
        status = self.order_statuses.change_to_addmat()
        self.assertEqual(status, 'Add Materials')
```

but i get

> **init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

How do i need to inerhit base class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are not overriding anything in the **init**() method here, it is unnecessary for you to include it in your StatusesCheckManual subclass.

If you do need to override **init**(), you'll need to do it in Environment as well, and be sure to include the same args:

```
class StatusesCheckManual(Environment):
    def __init__(self, methodName='runTest'):
        super(StatusesCheckManual, self).__init__(methodName)

class Environment(unittest.TestCase):
    def __init__(self, methodName='runTest'):
        super(Environment, self).__init__(methodName)
```

(please note the the first arg for super is the current class, not the parent)